# How to check if the image is colliding with a border?

Tags: javascript

I have a maze (auto generated, I suppose) and the maze is made by creating n*n divs. As the walls, I have borders and I need to count how many times the image collided with the "walls" of the maze.

This is how I set the borders for each div. (I'm aware that the code is kinda hard to understand, but I tried to give as much information I could for my problem)

```
function Bordere(){
for(var i =1; i<= BordereElement1.length; i+=2) { //in BordereElement1[0](0,2,4,6...99) i saved the div element 
//and in BordereElement1[1](1,3,5,7,9...100) is saved the booleans for borders
    if (BordereElement1[i - 1].topBorder === true) {
        BordereElement1[i].style.borderTop = "2px solid black";
    }
    if (BordereElement1[i - 1].bottomBorder === true) {
        BordereElement1[i].style.borderBottom = "2px solid black";
    }
    if (BordereElement1[i - 1].leftBorder === true) {
        BordereElement1[i].style.borderLeft = "2px solid black";
    }
    if (BordereElement1[i - 1].rightBorder === true) {
        BordereElement1[i].style.borderRight = "2px solid black";
    }
}
for(var j = 0; j<n; j++) { //outer borders
    document.getElementById("lab" + j + "" + (n-1)).style.borderRight = "5px solid black";
    document.getElementById("lab0" + j).style.borderTop = "5px solid black";
    document.getElementById("lab" + j + "0").style.borderLeft = "5px solid black";
    document.getElementById("lab" + (n-1) + "" + j).style.borderBottom = "5px solid black";
}
document.getElementById("lab0"+celulaStart).style.borderTop = "5px solid transparent"; //start border top
document.getElementById("lab"+ (n-1) + "" + celulaFinal).style.borderBottom = "5px solid transparent"; //end border bottom
```

}

And I'm kinda aware that this function is not so important :)

I need to use vanilla JS.

https://jsfiddle.net/gc9zw3t2/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest, i forgot about this question... I created the answer for my question and i'll "revive" this thread just to post my anwer just in case someone need this. At the end, we are a community and we try to help each other <3

Here's the code splitted: https://jsfiddle.net/6qafkLw0/14/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Maze-Labs</title>
        
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/231/231138.png">
        
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="https://fontlibrary.org//face/segment7" type="text/css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Akaya Kanadaka">
        
        <style>
            html {
              height: 100%;
              width: 100%;
            }

            body {
              max-height: 100%;
              background-color: #1974D2;
            }
            .header {
                    height: 8vh;
                    background-color: #6D9BC5;
                    border-style: solid;
                    border-color: #00308F;
                    border-width: 5px;
                    border-radius: 15px 10px 25px 15px;
                    color: #6D9BC5;
                    font-family: 'Akaya Kanadaka';
                    font-size: 1.5vmin;
            }
            .centerDiv{
                top: 50%;
                left: 50%;
                width: 100px;
                height: 100px;
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
                background-color: red;
                position: fixed;
            }
            .container{
                height: 85vh;
            }
            .ButCascada {
                background-color: #3498DB;
                color: white;
                padding: 16px;
                font-size: 16px;
                border: none;
                cursor: pointer;
            }
        </style>

        <script>
            /*Dezvoltați o pagină web cu facilități JavaScript care definește un labirint (componente div alăturate,
            dispuse matricial).
            O imagine (a carei dimensiuni ii permit să încapă în labirint) trebuie mutată cu cursorul, de la intrare spre
            ieșire.
            Se afișează în permanență numărul de coliziuni cu pereții labirintului. Se contorizează timpul scurs între
            intrarea în labirint și momentul ieșirii (număr de secunde).
            Aplicația are 2 butoane, Pauza și Restart.*/

            //imagine: https://doctorat.utcluj.ro/images/logo_site.png /212x108
            //img2?:https://admitereonline.utcluj.ro/storage/2021/02/logout02.png  //320px227px;

            //sursa: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_generation_algorithm

            /*
            1.Given a current cell as a parameter
            2.Mark the current cell as visited
            3.While the current cell has any unvisited neighbour cells:
                1.Choose one of the unvisited neighbours
                2.Remove the wall between the current cell and the chosen cell
                3.Invoke the routine recursively for the chosen cell
            */
            //let n=3;
            let min = `00`, sec = `00`;
            let contorColiziuni;
            function  createMaze(){
                n = prompt("Generare Labirint.[maxim 10] Introduceti dimensiunea:", 10);
                let wrapper = document.createElement("div"); wrapper.setAttribute("id", "wrapper"); wrapper.style.textAlign = "center"; wrapper.style.width = "100%";
                let spatiu = document.createElement("div"); spatiu.setAttribute("class", "StartZone");
                spatiu.style.position = "relative";
                let spatiu2 = document.createElement("div"); spatiu2.setAttribute("class", "finishZone");

                let DivControale = document.createElement("div"); DivControale.setAttribute("id", "divButoaneInfoText");
                    let pauza = document.createElement("button");
                    let restart = document.createElement("button");
                    let info = document.createElement("h2"); info.style.display = "inline";
                    let cron = document.createElement("h2"); cron.style.display = "inline";
                document.getElementById("content").appendChild(DivControale);
                DivControale.style.marginTop = "1%"; DivControale.style.display = "inline-block"; DivControale.style.width = "100%";
                DivControale.appendChild(pauza); DivControale.appendChild(restart); DivControale.appendChild(info); DivControale.appendChild(cron);
                pauza.setAttribute("id", "ButonPauza"); pauza.setAttribute("class", "ButCascada");
                restart.setAttribute("id","ButonRestart"); restart.setAttribute("class", "ButCascada"); restart.style.marginLeft = "1%";
                info.setAttribute("id", "infoText"); info.style.marginLeft = "1%"; info.style.width = "40%"; info.style.fontFamily = "Akaya Kanadaka"; info.innerHTML = `Numarul de coliziuni cu peretii labirintului: <span style="font-family: Segment7Standard;">${0}</span>`; //E DE FACUT
                cron.setAttribute("id", "cron");
                pauza.textContent = "Pauza"; pauza.setAttribute("onClick", "Pauza()"); ////////AICI E DE FACUT
                restart.textContent = "Restart"; restart.setAttribute("onClick", "Ex5()");
                cron.style.fontFamily = "Segment7Standard"; cron.textContent = "00:00"; cron.style.paddingLeft = "5%";


                spatiu.setAttribute("id", "start"); spatiu2.setAttribute("id", "sfarsit");
                spatiu.style.height = "100px"; spatiu2.style.height = "100px";
                spatiu.style.width = "100%"; spatiu2.style.width = "100%";
                imagine = document.createElement("img");
                imagine.setAttribute("id", "logoUTCN");
                imagine.style.zIndex = "1";
                imagine.style.width = (((n / n) * 100) / n) - 5  + "%";
                imagine.style.height= "auto";
                imagine.style.position = "absolute";
                imagine.style.left = "47.5%";
                imagine.style.border = "1px solid black";
                imagine.src = "https://doctorat.utcluj.ro/images/logo_site.png";
                //imagine.addEventListener("mousedown", mutare(), false);


                spatiu.appendChild(imagine);
                document.getElementById("content").appendChild(spatiu);
                document.getElementById("content").appendChild(wrapper);
                for(let i=0; i<n; i++) {
                    for (let j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                        var createDivs = document.createElement("div");
                        createDivs.style.background = "#6D9BC5";
                        createDivs.style.display = "inline-block";
                        createDivs.style.width = (((n / n) * 100) / n) -0.8  + "%";
                        createDivs.style.height = "100px";
                        createDivs.style.marginBottom = "-4px";
                        createDivs.style.border = "2px solid transparent";
                        createDivs.setAttribute("class", "Labirint");
                        createDivs.setAttribute("id", "lab" + i + "" + j);
                        wrapper.appendChild(createDivs);

                    }
                }

                for(var j = 0; j<n; j++) {
                    document.getElementById("lab" + j + "" + (n-1)).style.borderRight = "5px solid black";
                    document.getElementById("lab0" + j).style.borderTop = "5px solid black";
                    document.getElementById("lab" + j + "0").style.borderLeft = "5px solid black";
                    document.getElementById("lab" + (n-1) + "" + j).style.borderBottom = "5px solid black";
                }

                document.getElementById("content").appendChild(spatiu2);
                let border = +getComputedStyle((document.getElementById("lab02"))).borderTopWidth.slice(0, -2);

            }

            let LabirintSolved = false;
            function Pauza(){ //implementare resume? -implementat :) Musai verificat
                if(document.getElementById("cron").textContent != '00:00') {
                    if(LabirintSolved === false) {
                                    if (document.getElementById("ButonPauza").textContent == 'Pauza') {
                                            clearInterval(apelCron);
                                            apelCron = 0;
                                            document.getElementById("ButonPauza").textContent = 'Resume';
                                    } else if (document.getElementById("ButonPauza").textContent == 'Resume') {
                                            apelCron = setInterval(Cron, 1000);
                                            document.getElementById("ButonPauza").textContent = 'Pauza';
                                    }
                            } else {
                                    alert("Nu se mai poate interactiona cu cronometrul, labirintul a fost rezolvat!");
                            }
                }
            }

            let apelCron; //variabila in care se stocheaza intervalul
            function Cron() {
                let cron = document.getElementById("cron");
                sec ++
                if (sec < 10) {
                    sec = `0` + sec;
                }
                if (sec > 59) {
                    sec = `00`
                    min ++
                    if (min < 10) {
                        min = `0` + min
                    }
                }
                cron.textContent = min + ':' + sec;

            }

            let generareCompleta = false;
            let celulaCurenta;
            let celulaStart;
            let celulaFinal;
            //let Bordere = new Array(n*n).fill(0).map(() => new Array(5).fill(0));
            let BordereElement1 = []; //array in care imi salvez ce pereti trebuie sa fac (initial toti peretii is "true" in clasa)

            /*
            1.Choose the initial cell, mark it as visited and push it to the stack
            2.While the stack is not empty
                1.Pop a cell from the stack and make it a current cell
                2.If the current cell has any neighbours which have not been visited
                    1.Push the current cell to the stack
                    2.Choose one of the unvisited neighbours
                    3.Remove the wall between the current cell and the chosen cell
                    4.Mark the chosen cell as visited and push it to the stack
            */


            function generare(){ //?
                let grid = [];//new Array(n).fill(0).map(() => new Array(n).fill(0));
                let stack = [];

                for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                    let linie = [];//Se salveaza un rand intreg de celule in variabila asta
                    for (let j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                        let celula = new Celule(i, j, grid);
                        linie.push(celula); //se introduce un element in linie
                    }
                    grid.push(linie); //se face un array bidimensional
                }
                var start = RandomNumber(); //utilizat pe parcurs
                var finish = RandomNumber();

                celulaCurenta = grid[0][start]; //inceputul maze-ului? Pot sa implementez intrarea random? celulaCurenta = grid[0][Math.floor(Math.random()* n)] ?
                celulaStart = start;
                celulaFinal = finish;


                console.log(`start: ${celulaStart} \nfinish: ${celulaFinal}`);
                grid[n-1][finish].goal = true;

                //celulaCurenta.setAttribute("paLaVecin", "vizitat");
                //iesireMaze = grid1[n][Math.floor(Math.random()* n)]; //nu stiu daca o sa folosesc :D
                /*for(let i = 0; i<n; i++) {
                    for (let j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                        paLaVecinu(grid, i ,j);
                    }
                }*/
                functieRecursiva();
                function functieRecursiva(){
                    for(let i = 0; i< n; i++){
                        for(let j=0; j<n; j++) {
                            grid[i][j].AfisGenMaze();
                        }
                    }
                    let celulaUrmatoare = celulaCurenta.verificareVecin();
                    if (celulaUrmatoare) {
                        //celulaCurenta.setAttribute("paLaVecin", "vizitat");
                        celulaUrmatoare.vizitat = true;
                        stack.push(celulaCurenta);
                        celulaCurenta.StergereBordere(celulaCurenta, celulaUrmatoare);
                        celulaCurenta.PatraticaGeneratoare();
                        //StergereBordere(celulaCurenta, celulaUrmatoare)
                        celulaCurenta = celulaUrmatoare;
                    } else if (stack.length > 0) {
                        let celula = stack.pop();
                        //celulaCurenta.PatraticaGeneratoare();
                        celulaCurenta = celula;
                    }
                    if (stack.length === 0) {
                        generareCompleta = true;
                        return;
                    }
                    window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
                        functieRecursiva();
                    });
                }
            }
            function RandomNumber(){
                let x = Math.floor(Math.random() * ((n-1) - 0 + 1) + 0);

                console.log(`In Random: ${x}`);
                if((x<0)||(x>n)){
                    RandomNumber();
                } else {
                    return x;
                }
            }
            function Bordere(){
                for(var i =1; i<= BordereElement1.length; i+=2) { //De ce 2???! SA PUN COMENTARII MAI DESSS!----parcurg vectorul din 2 in 2 pentru ca pe pozitiile pare am salvat array-ul cu booleans pentru pereti, iar cele impare cu elementul div respectiv
                    if (BordereElement1[i - 1].topBorder === true) {
                        BordereElement1[i].style.borderTop = "2px solid black";
                    }
                    if (BordereElement1[i - 1].bottomBorder === true) {
                        BordereElement1[i].style.borderBottom = "2px solid black";
                    }
                    if (BordereElement1[i - 1].leftBorder === true) {
                        BordereElement1[i].style.borderLeft = "2px solid black";
                    }
                    if (BordereElement1[i - 1].rightBorder === true) {
                        BordereElement1[i].style.borderRight = "2px solid black";
                    }
                }
                for(var j = 0; j<n; j++) {
                    document.getElementById("lab" + j + "" + (n-1)).style.borderRight = "5px solid black";  //generare border exterior
                    document.getElementById("lab0" + j).style.borderTop = "5px solid black";
                    document.getElementById("lab" + j + "0").style.borderLeft = "5px solid black";
                    document.getElementById("lab" + (n-1) + "" + j).style.borderBottom = "5px solid black";
                }
                document.getElementById("lab0"+celulaStart).style.borderTop = "5px solid transparent"; //pt celula start si finish
                document.getElementById("lab"+ (n-1) + "" + celulaFinal).style.borderBottom = "5px solid transparent";
                    
                    //setareBordereOglindaPentruElementulUrmator
                    for(var i = 0; i < n; i++){
                    for(var j = 1; j < (n-1); j++){
                                    //ca sa fac la toate, trebuie sa trec prin fiecare linia la fiecare coloana? Si pentru fiecare coloana la fiecare linie?
                                    let id = document.getElementById("lab" + i + "" + j);
                                    let idUrmColoana = document.getElementById("lab" + i + "" + (j+1));
                                    let idAntColoana = document.getElementById("lab" + i + "" + (j-1));
                                    if(id.style.borderRightColor === 'black') {
                                            idUrmColoana.style.borderLeftColor = 'black';
                                    }
                                    if(id.style.borderLeftColor === 'black') {
                                            idAntColoana.style.borderRightColor = 'black';
                                    }
                                    if(idAntColoana.style.borderRightColor === 'black') {
                                            id.style.borderLeftColor = 'black';
                                    }
                                    if(idUrmColoana.style.borderLeftColor === 'black') {
                                            id.style.borderRightColor = 'black';
                                    }
                            }
                    }
                    for(var i = 1; i < (n-1); i++){
                    for(var j = 0; j < n; j++){
                                    let id = document.getElementById("lab" + i + "" + j);
                                    let idUrmLinie = document.getElementById("lab" + (i+1) + "" + j);
                                    let idAntLinie = document.getElementById("lab" + (i-1) + "" + j);
                                    if(id.style.borderBottomColor === 'black') { //lab[x,y] are border-ul de jos negru, lab[x+1,y] o sa aibe border-ul de sus negru
                                            idUrmLinie.style.borderTopColor = 'black';
                                    }
                                    if(id.style.borderTopColor === 'black') { //lab[x,y] are border-ul de jos negru, lab[x+1,y] o sa aibe border-ul de sus negru
                                            idAntLinie.style.borderBottomColor = 'black';
                                    }
                                    if(idAntLinie.style.borderBottomColor === 'black'){
                                            id.style.borderTopColor = 'black';
                                    }
                                    if(idUrmLinie.style.borderTopColor === 'black') {
                                            id.style.borderBottomColor = 'black';
                                    }
                            }
                    }
            }
            class Celule {
                constructor(linia, coloana, matrice) {
                    this.linia = linia;
                    this.coloana = coloana;
                    this.ElementDiv = document.getElementById("lab" + linia + "" + coloana);
                    this.vizitat = false;
                    this.borders = { //dupa vectorul asta se schimba borderu' din transparent in black
                        topBorder: true,
                        rightBorder: true,
                        bottomBorder: true,
                        leftBorder: true,
                    };
                    this.goal = false;
                    this.grid = matrice;
                }
                verificareVecin() {
                    let grid = this.grid;
                    let linia = this.linia;
                    let coloana = this.coloana;
                    let vecini = [];

                    let vecinSus = linia !== 0 ? grid[linia - 1][coloana] : undefined;
                    let vecinDreapta = coloana !== grid.length - 1 ? grid[linia][coloana + 1] : undefined;
                    let vecinJos = linia !== grid.length - 1 ? grid[linia + 1][coloana] : undefined;
                    let vecinStanga = coloana !== 0 ? grid[linia][coloana - 1] : undefined;

                    if (vecinSus && !vecinSus.vizitat) {
                        vecini.push(vecinSus);
                    }
                    if (vecinDreapta && !vecinDreapta.vizitat) {
                        vecini.push(vecinDreapta);
                    }
                    if (vecinJos && !vecinJos.vizitat) {
                        vecini.push(vecinJos);
                    }
                    if (vecinStanga && !vecinStanga.vizitat) {
                        vecini.push(vecinStanga);
                    }

                    if (vecini.length !== 0) {
                        let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * vecini.length);
                        return vecini[random];
                    } else {
                        return undefined;
                    }
                }
                PatraticaGeneratoare() {
                    if(generareCompleta) {
                        this.ElementDiv.style.background ="#1974D2";
                    } else {
                        this.ElementDiv.style.background = "darkred";
                    }
                }
                StergereBordere(celula1, celula2) {
                    let x = celula1.coloana - celula2.coloana; //Se ia celula anterioara si se calculeaza pe orizontala. Daca da 1, inseamna ca generarea a fost facuta de la dreapta la stanga
                    if (x === 1) {
                        celula1.borders.leftBorder = false; //se elimina booleanul pentru peretele din stanga. Dupa ma folosesc de aceste boolean-uri la setarea culorii la borders.
                        celula2.borders.rightBorder = false;
                    } else if (x === -1) {
                        celula1.borders.rightBorder = false; //stanga la dreapta, pe verticala
                        celula2.borders.leftBorder = false;
                    }
                    let y = celula1.linia - celula2.linia; //daca e 1, e de jos in sus
                    if (y === 1) {
                        celula1.borders.topBorder = false;
                        celula2.borders.bottomBorder = false;
                    } else if (y === -1) { //de sus in jos
                        celula1.borders.bottomBorder = false;
                        celula2.borders.topBorder = false;
                    }
                    //DE AIA MERG DIN 2 IN 2 :)
                    BordereElement1.push(this.borders); //Imi introduc toate boolean-urile intr-un array unidimensional (length/2 pentru a putea afisa un anumit tip de date)
                    BordereElement1.push(this.ElementDiv); //salvez si div-urile pt care trebuie aplicate boolean-urile salvate
                }
                AfisGenMaze() {
                    if (this.vizitat) {
                        this.ElementDiv.style.background = "#1974D2"; //ca sa suprapun culoarea "darkred" cu care afisez generarea maze-ului
                    }
                    if (this.goal) {
                        this.ElementDiv.style.background = "rgba(0,255,0,0.2)"; //patratica care e iesirea
                                    this.ElementDiv.style.bottomBorderColor = 'darkred';
                    }
                }
            }


            function Ex5(){
                min = `00`; sec = `00`; coliziuni = 0; ultimaColiziune = null;
                clearInterval(apelCron); apelCron = 0; startMaze = true;
                generareCompleta = false;
                try{
                    const myNode = document.getElementById("content");
                    while (myNode.lastElementChild) {
                        myNode.removeChild(myNode.lastElementChild);
                    }
                } catch (e){}
                createMaze();
                generare();
                setTimeout(() => {Bordere();}, (n/3)*1000);
                ParcurgereLabirint();
            }
            var ultimaColiziune, coliziune = false, coliziuni = 0, startMaze = true;
            function ParcurgereLabirint() {
                let img = document.getElementById("logoUTCN");

                img.onmousedown = function (event) {
                    let shiftX = event.clientX - img.getBoundingClientRect().left;
                    let shiftY = event.clientY - img.getBoundingClientRect().top;
                    img.style.zIndex = 1000;

                    if(startMaze === true){
                        apelCron = setInterval(Cron, 1000);
                        startMaze = false;
                    }

                    moveAt(event.pageX, event.pageY);

                    function moveAt(pageX, pageY) {
                        img.style.left = pageX - shiftX - 8 + 'px';
                        img.style.top = pageY - shiftY - 124 + 'px';
                    }

                    function onMouseMove(event) {
                        moveAt(event.pageX, event.pageY);

                        info = document.getElementById("infoText");
                        info.innerHTML = `Numarul de coliziuni cu peretii labirintului: <span style="font-family: Segment7Standard;">${coliziuni}</span>`;

                        img.hidden = true; //ca sa treaca cursoru' prin poza ca sa ia div-ul de sub img
                        let elemBelow = document.elementFromPoint(event.clientX, event.clientY);
                        img.hidden = false;

                        if (!elemBelow) return;

                        let idDivLab = elemBelow.closest('.Labirint');

                        //console.log(idDivLab);
                        if(elemBelow.closest('.Labirint')) {
                            let borderStanga = idDivLab.style.borderLeftColor;
                            let borderSus = idDivLab.style.borderTopColor;
                            let borderDreapta = idDivLab.style.borderRightColor;
                            let borderJos = idDivLab.style.borderBottomColor;
                            //console.log(parseInt(img.style.left.slice(0,-2)) - idDivLab.getBoundingClientRect().left);
                            //console.log(`Stanga ${borderStanga}\nSus: ${borderSus}\nDreapta: ${borderDreapta}\nJos: ${borderJos}`);
                            let idUrmatorColoana = idDivLab.getAttribute("id"); //pt dreapta daca div-ul actual nu are border in dreapta
                            if(parseInt(idUrmatorColoana.slice(-1))<n){
                                idUrmatorColoana = idUrmatorColoana.substring(0, 4) + (parseInt(idUrmatorColoana.slice(-1))+1);
                            }
                            let idAnteriorColoana = idDivLab.getAttribute("id"); //pt stanga in caz ca div-ul actual nu are border in stanga si sa verific pentru borderu' din dreapta
                            if(parseInt(idAnteriorColoana.slice(-1))>0){
                                idAnteriorColoana = idAnteriorColoana.substring(0, 4) + (parseInt(idAnteriorColoana.slice(-1))-1);
                            }
                            let idUrmatorLinie = idDivLab.getAttribute("id"); //pt border-ul de jos in caz ca div-ul actual nu are si verific borderu' de sus la div-ul de sub cel actual
                            if(parseInt(idUrmatorLinie.slice(3,4))<n){
                                idUrmatorLinie = idUrmatorLinie.substring(0, 3) + (parseInt(idUrmatorLinie.slice(3,4)) + 1) + idUrmatorLinie.substring(4);
                            }
                            let idAnteriorLinie = idDivLab.getAttribute("id");//pt border-ul de sus in caz ca div-ul actual nu are si verific borderu' de jos la div-ul deasupra celui actual
                            if(parseInt(idAnteriorLinie.slice(3,4))>0){
                                idAnteriorLinie = idAnteriorLinie.substring(0, 3) + (parseInt(idAnteriorLinie.slice(3,4)) - 1) + idAnteriorLinie.substring(4);
                            }
                            if ((borderStanga === "black") && (img.getBoundingClientRect().left - idDivLab.getBoundingClientRect().left < 6)) {
                                //console.log("stanga: " + (img.getBoundingClientRect().left - idDivLab.getBoundingClientRect().left));
                                                    if(coliziune == true) {
                                    if(ultimaColiziune != idDivLab) {
                                        coliziuni += 1;
                                        coliziune = true;
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    coliziuni += 1;
                                    coliziune = true;
                                }
                                //console.log("Stanga sub limita!\n" + (img.getBoundingClientRect().left - document.getElementById(idAnteriorColoana).getBoundingClientRect().right));
                                ultimaColiziune = idDivLab;
                                console.log(coliziuni);
                                document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
                            }

                            if ((borderSus === "black") && (img.getBoundingClientRect().top - idDivLab.getBoundingClientRect().top) < 5){
                                //console.log("sus: " + (img.getBoundingClientRect().top - idDivLab.getBoundingClientRect().top));
                                if(coliziune == true) {
                                    if(ultimaColiziune != idDivLab) {
                                        coliziuni += 1;
                                        coliziune = true;
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    coliziuni += 1;
                                    coliziune = true;
                                }
                                ultimaColiziune = idDivLab;
                                console.log(coliziuni);
                                document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
                            }

                            if ((borderDreapta === "black") && (idDivLab.getBoundingClientRect().right - img.getBoundingClientRect().right) < 7) { //sa iau si borderu' stang de la j+1!!!!
                                //console.log("Dreapta");
                               // console.log("dreapta: " + (idDivLab.getBoundingClientRect().right - img.getBoundingClientRect().right)); //<7
                                if(coliziune == true) {
                                    if(ultimaColiziune != idDivLab) {
                                        coliziuni += 1;
                                        coliziune = true;
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    coliziuni += 1;
                                    coliziune = true;
                                }
                                //console.log("idLinieUrmator: " + idLinieUrmator + "\nDreapta sub limita!\n" + (img.getBoundingClientRect().right - document.getElementById(idUrmatorLinie).getBoundingClientRect().left));
                                ultimaColiziune = idDivLab;
                                console.log(coliziuni);
                                document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
                            }
                            if ((borderJos === "black") && (idDivLab.getBoundingClientRect().bottom - img.getBoundingClientRect().bottom < 5)) {
                                //console.log("jos: " + (idDivLab.getBoundingClientRect().bottom - img.getBoundingClientRect().bottom));
                                if(coliziune == true) {
                                    if(ultimaColiziune != idDivLab) {
                                        coliziuni += 1;
                                        coliziune = true;
                                    } else {
                                        coliziuni += 1;
                                        coliziune = true;
                                    }
                                }
                                //console.log("Jos sub limita!\n" + (document.getElementById(idUrmatorColoana).getBoundingClientRect().top - img.getBoundingClientRect().bottom));
                                ultimaColiziune = idDivLab;
                                document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
                            }
                        } //else if (document.elementFromPoint(event.clientX, event.clientY).closest('.finishZone')){
                        else if ((document.getElementById("sfarsit").getBoundingClientRect().bottom - img.getBoundingClientRect().bottom > 5)&&(document.getElementById("sfarsit").getBoundingClientRect().right - img.getBoundingClientRect().right > 5)&&(img.getBoundingClientRect().top - document.getElementById("sfarsit").getBoundingClientRect().top > 5)&&(img.getBoundingClientRect().left - document.getElementById("sfarsit").getBoundingClientRect().left > 5)){
                            clearInterval(apelCron);
                            apelareCron = 0;
                            document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
                                            LabirintSolved = true;
                            alert(`Felicitari! Ati terminat maze-ul in ${min}:${sec}! Numarul de coliziuni cu peretii: ${coliziuni}`)
                        }
                    }

                    document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);

                    img.onmouseup = function () {
                        document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
                        img.onmouseup = null;
                    };

                };

                img.ondragstart = function () { //nu vreau sa se activeze draggu'
                    return false;
                };
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload=Ex5()>

        <div id="content" class="container">
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

The code needs some tweaks on image boundaries to match the height and width of the space between walls, the image doesn't snap to the cursor in the middle. (details in my opinion, the thing that was important it's working[almost perfect :) ])

Answer (score 0):

This is what i did so far... Can someone please tell me a better way to get the position for the image? (Shall i use "getBoundingClientRect().left/.right/.top/.bottom" for making the delta between image-element? The problem is that the position for img is absolute, and if i resize the window, the position will not be the same.)

```
    let img = document.getElementById("logoUTCN");

    img.onmousedown = function (event) {
        let shiftX = event.clientX - img.getBoundingClientRect().left;
        let shiftY = event.clientY - img.getBoundingClientRect().top;
        img.style.zIndex = 1000;

        if(startMaze === true){
            apelareCronometru = setInterval(Cron, 1000);
            startMaze = false;
        }

        moveAt(event.pageX, event.pageY);

        function moveAt(pageX, pageY) {
            img.style.left = pageX - shiftX - 8 + 'px';
            img.style.top = pageY - shiftY - 127 + 'px';
        }

        function onMouseMove(event) {
            moveAt(event.pageX, event.pageY);

            info = document.getElementById("infoText");
            info.innerText = `Numarul de coliziuni cu peretii labirintului: ${coliziuni}`;

            let elemBelow = document.elementFromPoint(event.clientX, event.clientY);

            if (!elemBelow) return;

            let idDivLab = elemBelow.closest('.Labirint');

            if(elemBelow.closest('.Labirint')) {
                let borderStanga = idDivLab.style.borderLeftColor;
                let borderSus = idDivLab.style.borderTopColor;
                let borderDreapta = idDivLab.style.borderRightColor;
                let borderJos = idDivLab.style.borderBottomColor;

                if ((borderStanga === "black") && ((parseInt(img.style.left.slice(0, -2)) - idDivLab.getBoundingClientRect().left) < -5)) {
                    console.log(parseInt(img.style.left.slice(0, -2)) - idDivLab.getBoundingClientRect().left);
                    if(coliziune == true) {
                        if(ultimaColiziune != idDivLab) {
                            coliziuni += 1;
                            coliziune = true;
                        }
                    } else {
                        coliziuni += 1;
                        coliziune = true;
                    }
                    ultimaColiziune = idDivLab;
                    console.log(coliziuni);
                    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
                }

                if ((borderSus === "black") && ((parseInt(img.style.top.slice(0, -2)) - idDivLab.getBoundingClientRect().top) < -118)) {
                    console.log(parseInt(img.style.top.slice(0, -2)) - idDivLab.getBoundingClientRect().top);
                    if(coliziune == true) {
                        if(ultimaColiziune != idDivLab) {
                            coliziuni += 1;
                            coliziune = true;
                        }
                    } else {
                        coliziuni += 1;
                        coliziune = true;
                    }
                    ultimaColiziune = idDivLab;
                    console.log(coliziuni);
                    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
                }

                if ((borderDreapta === "black") && ((parseInt(img.style.left.slice(0, -2) - idDivLab.getBoundingClientRect().right)) > -80)) {
                    console.log(parseInt(img.style.left.slice(0, -2)) - idDivLab.getBoundingClientRect().right);
                    if(coliziune == true) {
                        if(ultimaColiziune != idDivLab) {
                            coliziuni += 1;
                            coliziune = true;
                        }
                    } else {
                        coliziuni += 1;
                        coliziune = true;
                    }
                    ultimaColiziune = idDivLab;
                    console.log(coliziuni);
                    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
                }
                if ((borderJos === "black") && (parseInt(img.style.top.slice(0, -2)) - idDivLab.getBoundingClientRect().bottom > -160)) {
                    console.log(parseInt(img.style.top.slice(0, -2)) - idDivLab.getBoundingClientRect().bottom);
                    if(coliziune == true) {
                        if(ultimaColiziune != idDivLab) {
                            coliziuni += 1;
                            coliziune = true;
                        } else {
                            coliziuni += 1;
                            coliziune = true;
                        }
                    }
                    ultimaColiziune = idDivLab;
                    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
                }
            } else if (document.elementFromPoint(event.clientX, event.clientY).closest('.finishZone')){
                clearInterval(apelCron);
                apelCron = 0;
                alert(`Felicitari! Ati terminat maze-ul in ${min}:${sec}! Numarul de coliziuni cu peretii:${coliziuni}`)
            }
        }

        document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);

        img.onmouseup = function () {
            document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
            img.onmouseup = null;
        };

    };

    img.ondragstart = function () {
        return false;
    };
}
```

Also, how many times image collided with the walls is not implemented in the best way. It could be improved in n ways, but I can't see other solution :( .

Comment: I understand how frustrating it is but sometimes for complex problems like this your the one who has the best solutions. I believe in you. also if your doing animations try using a library like p5 itll make your life easier